# User based pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I'm looking to find out a way to create a pop up window that prompt a user a question, and in the window I'd like to have a checkbox saying "Don't display this message again". I'm not quite sure how to go about this, I've done a bit of research but I've found nothing, I'd love to be able to find out how so I can help the community with the result!

So to sum up, I want a pop up window that checks if the user has "checked" do not display, then it will not perform the function, the function and jquery is fine I can do all that, but as for the "per user" request, I've got no idea :(

I'd love the help guys!

Comment: use some kind of client side storage such as cookies or local storage

Comment: Show some of your code. Whatever that you've tried so far. Only the fact that your have done some "RnD" will not help us to help you in any good way. With the information you've shared in this question, I can only give you the "idea" how you can go about it. PS : Be as specific as you can with your questions

Comment: Hi @Maverick, I didn't know what to search for, hence why I came here, I believe my question is pretty specific, I don't know how much more specific I can be :( regardless, I have no code for the USER function, I've got absolutely zero idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming PHP:

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
       var doNotShow = TRUE;
       //the chekbox has been checked, the user does not want to see this again.
       $.ajax({
         url: 'path/to/my/controller.ext',
         data: 'doNotShow='+doNotShow,
         success: function(data){
           //the data has been sent to the server, close the popup box, do whatever is necessary here.
           // change the window location, whatever.
         }
       });

   }
});
```

The serverside PHP code (path/to/my/controller.ext) --

```
if(isset($_POST['doNotShow']) && $_POST['doNotShow'] == TRUE):
  $_SESSION['doNotShow'] = $_POST['doNotShow'];
endif;
```

Now, before you load that dialog box, you'll want to add some PHP conditionalizing it.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['doNotShow'])):
?>
    //javascript to launch the popup, the session is not set.
<?php
elseif(isset($_SESSION['doNotShow']) && ($_SESSION['doNotShow'] == TRUE)):
?>
    //don't launch the popup, they don't want to see it, whatever..
<?php
endif;
```

Comment: Hi, This is a little daunting, I'm not great at all with PHP, to be honest I've never really used it before! Is this the simplest of ways you know of? Sorry, I'm not trying to be rude at all!

Comment: @Shannon Don't be afraid of PHP, it's a very straight forward system. The only other option to store values is to A) use a database (still requires a server-side scripting language), B) read/write to a file (still requires a server-side scripting language), C) use HTML5 localstorage (no server-side scripting required, hackable, only supported on newest browsers leaving others in the dust) or D) Use Cookies (no server-side scripting, easily deleted by user)

Answer (score 3):

For popup you can use `Twitter Bootstarp Modol` here is the link - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals .And also you can add your  conditions in the modol and check wheather the user checked or not.